# What does useNavigate replace option do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The [docs](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate#usenavigate) say:

> Either pass a `To` value (same type as `<Link to>`) with an optional
> second `{ replace, state }` arg or

without saying what it does. So does it replace the whole history stack or just the current route? I have no idea.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `replace` options property is a REPLACE navigation action. It's a redirect, replacing the current entry in the history stack versus PUSHing a new entry onto the top like a regular navigation.

```
navigate(path); // PUSH, navigate
navigate(path, { replace: true }); // REPLACE, redirect
```

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

> The `useNavigate` hook returns a function that lets you navigate
> programmatically, for example after a form is submitted. If using
> `replace: true`, ***the navigation will replace the current entry in the
> history stack instead of adding a new one***.

Comment: How would one replace the whole history stack if they wanted to?

Comment: @sdfsdf Off hand I'm not entirely sure. The history stack is in the browser. Some versions of the `history` object can tell you the length of the history stack, but I've not seen anything in RRD that allows you to reset it. You might need to go outside React and look at the `window.history`, the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) doesn't appear to expose out this functionality either though.

Comment: What's the point to replace the current entry in history? Is it like we show that we do redirection? If yes, why wouldn't we use the function "redirect" then?

Comment: @HackerMF That depends on the use case, but it's often useful in authentication flows where you redirect to a login page and need to redirect back to the original page being accessed, you don't want the login page to remain in the history stack to be accessed via a back navigation. The `useNavigate` hook returns only a `navigate` function. You "redirect" via a REPLACE action by specifying the `replace: true` property in the options argument. `navigate(path, { replace: true })` replaces `history.replace(path)` from older RRD versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like;

```
import { useLocation, Navigate } from "react-router-dom"

const location = useLocation ()

‹Navigate to="/" state={{ from: location }} replace /›
```

See here for more details; https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).